# In Matplotlib ax.texts container is empty, why?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am little lost and need help here.

I am trying to add a text to axes via Text. I know you can do it with ax.text, ax.annotate but I need to use Text. Don't ask me why :)
Below is my simple code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.text import Text

txt1 = Text(text='Dude', x=0.5, y=0.5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(txt1)
```

In Matplotlib documentation, it states that for Artists that have no **add_** method, you can use **add_artist**.
So I did. However, when you add a text, should it not become available in **ax.texts** container?

When I run,

```
ax.texts
```

it returns an empty list. 
However, when you use ax.annotate or ax.text, there is no problem with the ax.texts container.

Can anyone explain why, and how can I get it right using **Text** Artist?

Comment: What result are you trying to get?

Comment: There should not be any reason not to use `ax.text`, so indeed, one would ask why you need to create that `Text` instance manually.

Comment: Second thing: Why do you need the text being present inside of `ax.texts`? All in all this sounds a lot like an [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Thanks for your questions. Here is why I am doing what I am doing.
I am trying to understand the anatomy of Matplotlib and how things work in the back scene.

For example, you can call **Line2D** Artist and add it to axes with **ax.add_line**. It immediately becomes available in ax.lines

Also it works when you call **Rectangle** Artist and add it to axes with **ax.add_patch**. and it also becomes available in its relevant container, which is **ax.patches**

Why on earth this consistency does not work for Text?

Comment: because you used `ax.add_artist`, it appears in the `ax.artists` list.

Comment: @tom you are right. It appears in ax.artists, as there is no add_text. It is the Matplotlib documentation that is confusing, as it states __if add__ misses use add_artist__. So I assumed, it should take care of the rest itself. 

One question, what is the purpose of from **matplotlib.text import Text** if Text(...) cannot be added to axes like other artists. 

The lack of consistency is tripping me really.

Comment: I was about to write an answer that mentioned the hidden `_add_text`, but @ImportanceOfBeingErnest beat me to it. So, see his answer!

Comment: haha)) True, he did it. But thank you @tom

Comment: Which part of the matplotlib documentation are you refering to here?

Answer (score 1):

The way matplotlib internally adds a `Text` to the axes, if `ax.text` is called, is by calling

```
ax._add_text(..)
```

So you may replace the line `ax.add_artist(txt1)` in your code by

```
ax._add_text(txt1)
```

Doing so, the `Text` instance will be available inside the `ax.texts` list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.text import Text

txt1 = Text(text='Dude', x=0.5, y=0.5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax._add_text(txt1)
print(ax.texts)
plt.show()
```

And the reason it is  in that list is straight that the `_add_text` method calls `self.texts.append(txt)`. So you may even replicate the [complete content of `_add_text`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/4b5f6e35b614669d2cf66cf7169a44ed10fd4702/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L1886)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.text import Text

txt1 = Text(text='Dude', x=0.5, y=0.5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax._set_artist_props(txt1)
ax.texts.append(txt1)
txt1._remove_method = lambda h: ax.texts.remove(h)
ax.stale = True

print(ax.texts)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You ROCKKK. Can you point out where I can read more on this (__add_text) @importanceofbeingernest

Comment: Much appreciated. You saved me from going mad